# Blueimp File Uploader - Chrome folder upload limitations

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, file-upload, blueimp

Only chrome 22 and later supports uploading relative folder names at dragging and dropping folders on browser upload (html5).

When i am trying to upload multiple files with chrome drag&drop folder support, i am experiencing some kind of limitation. And i couldn't find any way to change or disable this limitation.

- When you just select 1000 files and drop to uploader it does work and adds those files to upload list after waiting for a while for processing. That is ok.
- When you select a folder including 1000 files inside and drop to uploader, then uploader just adds random 100 files in that folder.
- When you create 110 folders, then include 1 file each in folders, then uploader adds just 100 files leaving 10 folders out.

It seems, chrome file/folder upload mechanism somehow limits maximum items in any folder while recursively crawling files & folders. And limitation number is 100.

I couldn't find any related documentation, and i am desperately in need for raising that limit to 1000 file/folder each at minimum or no limit.

Thank you all already.

Comment: Hey @wmwmwm Can you tell us how you are handling the folder uploads in the backend?

Comment: Hi @karthik-k, we are not using original handler for uploader. We are using our own software. But you can use data.files[0].relativePath at bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) { section of the main uploader javascript. It may also post this value on upload. If it does not, you can add easily from uploader javascript.

Answer (score 2):

After searching relevant documentation for 2 days, i could find an answer in following url.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DirectoryReader#readEntries

And i could able to fix blueimp uploader.

in **jquery.fileupload.js**

Find:

```
            } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
            dirReader = entry.createReader();
            dirReader.readEntries(function (entries) {
                that._handleFileTreeEntries(
                    entries,
                    path + entry.name + '/'
                ).done(function (files) {
                    dfd.resolve(files);
                }).fail(errorHandler);
            }, errorHandler);
        } else {
```

Replace:

```
        } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
            dirReader = entry.createReader();

            var entries = [];

            var readEntries = function () {
                dirReader.readEntries(function (results /* entries */) {

                    if (results.length) {
                        entries = entries.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(results || [], 0));
                        readEntries();
                    } else {
                        that._handleFileTreeEntries(
                            entries,
                            path + entry.name + '/'
                        ).done(function (files) {
                            dfd.resolve(files);
                        }).fail(errorHandler);
                    }

                }, errorHandler);
            };

            readEntries();

        } else {
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: By the way, this bug seems to fixed in recent versions of jquery uploader. If you are using latest version, then nevermind this post.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/commit/911dcf1f5bbfda877573fd4fb2b67dd47f225752